# Easy way to find the key in a map given a binding, Ocaml

Tags: dictionary, ocaml

I am not very familiar with Map module in Ocaml.

I have a simple map `m: string Map.Make(Int).t` from `int` to `string`, and I know that every binding (`:string`) is unique. I would like to write a funciton `find_from_string_to_int: string -> string Map.Make(Int).t -> int`, could anyone help? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is an infrequent operation, the easiest way is to fold over all the (key,value) bindings of the map `SMap.fold`:

```
# module SMap = Map.Make(String);;
# let reverse v t =
  SMap.fold (fun k v' acc -> if v = v' then Some k else acc) t None;;
val reverse : 'a -> 'a SMap.t -> SMap.key option = <fun>
```

If this is a common operation, what you're looking for is a bidirectional map (a map that can be queried in both "directions"). The easiest way is to carry around a pair of maps: `int IMap.t * string SMap.t` (accesses in both direction are logarithmic, while the `reverse` above is linear in the size of the map). You could also implement a dedicated data structure, but that's probably not worth the added complexity.

PS: `reverse` could be optimized to quit the iteration early if the value is found, but if it's an uncommon operation it's not really important anyway.